# Is it possible to keep first open tag and last close tag using xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

can we write a code to keep first open  tag and last close  tag using xslt.

example code look like:

Sample input xml:

```
<jobId>
    <bov>text</bov>
    <grade>text</grade>
</jobId>
<jobId>
    <placeholder>text</placeholder>
</jobId>
```

expected output xml:

```
<jobId>
    <bov>text</bov>
    <grade>text</grade>
    <placeholder>text</placeholder>
</jobId>
```

---

As suggested in the comments after adding root element, I'm able to generate the expected output xml.

after modification input xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="5.xsl" ?>
<Root>
    <jobId>
        <bov>text</bov>
        <grade>text</grade>
    </jobId>
    <jobId>
        <placeholder>text</placeholder>
    </jobId>
</Root>
```

XSLT will look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <jobId>
            <xsl:for-each select="Root/jobId" >
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </jobId>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. However, your example is not usable because the input is not well-formed XML (has no single root element ). Also please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to write your code for you.

Comment: So you want to merge elements with the same tag? could you add more complex examples of xml inputs/outputs?

Comment: It might for instance be a use case for grouping by node name or by grouping adjacent elements, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info for some samples in XSLT 3 and 2.

Comment: I doubt grouping is required here. A simple `<jobId><xsl:copy-of select="jobId/*"/></jobId>` could well be all that's needed.

Comment: Hi @Tranbi, Thanks for your reply. Yes I want to merge the elements in the same tag. I have updated the question with root element.

Comment: Hi @MartinHonnen, Thanks for sharing the useful information.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k , Thanks for your comment after adding root element it worked. I am new to XSLT, I forgot to add the XSLT which I have tried. <jobId><xsl:copy-of select="jobId/*"/></jobId> helped me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, your stylesheet can be simplified to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <jobId>
        <xsl:copy-of select="jobId/*"/>
    </jobId>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```